# How do I prove that $\cot(\theta) =\frac{ \cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I attached a picture of the problem if there were any confusions on how the problem was formatted. [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq1QE.jpg) is to show:
 $$\cot(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$$

Comment: What's your definition of $\cot$?

Comment: If $\vartheta=\theta$, the answer is "by definition".

Comment: How do you define $\cot$? Unless you tell us that, we cannot help you.

Comment: All it asked was to prove that cot equals cos and sin, no values were given.

Comment: I took a screenshot of the question and what's on there is what the question is asking. Other than (θ) there is nothing else given.

Comment: My guess is then that the answer below is what you are after, which uses the definition $\cot \theta \equiv \frac{1}{\tan \theta}$.

Comment: @Crystal The question is only asking that because it *assumes* you already know what $\cot$ is. That definition was what I was asking about.

Comment: Crystal, you have been repeatedly asked what **definition** of cotangent you are using and you have not answered that.  You can't just repeat the problem since you can't answer a question about "cotangent" without knowing what "cotangent" **means**!  What does "cotangent" mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when asked to answer questions like this, you are given a list of identities to form a basis of proof.

A likely list of identities would include:
$\tan(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$ and $\cot(\theta) = \frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$.

Given this knowledge, we can compute: 
$$\cot(\theta) = 
\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)} = \frac{1}{\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}} = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}.$$

Thus $\cot(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}$

You can prove the above by considering a right angled triangle.

Then $\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}=\cot(\theta) = \frac{1}{\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}}$

The first equality above is by definition.

So $\cot(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$